# Using $PWD to get parent directory's basename in makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

I need to automate a variable alignment in my Makefile. My Makefile's full file path is:

```
/home/e2/branchname/projectname/modulename/Makefile
```

In my Makefile, I have a variable `BUILD_DIR`, a part of which should be equal to the `branchname` in the full path.

So I did this:

```
BRANCH_NAME= $(shell cd ../.. && basename "$PWD" && cd projectname/modulename)
BUILD_DIR=$(HOME)/$(BRANCH_NAME)/build
```

Apparently I expected `BUILD_DIR` to be `~/branchname/build` here, but after `make` I got `~/WD/build` instead. I think it's most likely that I got a wrong `BRANCH_NAME`. Is there something wrong with what I did? And if yes I'd like to get some advice about how to do it correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because `$` has a special meaning to Make, so if you want to pass that up to shell you have to "escape" it.  In case of Make, you escape the dollar sign by doubling.  So you have to use `$$PWD`.

Also, what you are doing is not really the best way - it is always best to avoid the shell and use Make functionality if possible.  In your case, the best way to do what you want is this:

```
BUILD_DIR := $(abspath $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))/../../build)
```

You have to put the above line in the makefile in question, near the top, so that it is before you `include` any other makefiles.

Comment: but, if I use `$(PWD)`, it gives me `modulename` instead of `branchname`.

Comment: @wangx1ng I corrected my answer, it was wrong at first.  Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, `$$PWD` did the work! the `abspath` solution  is accidentally right in this specific case and it gives me `~/branchname/build`. But I should be able to get the `branchname` part here because the `BRANCH_NAME` is also needed by some where else in my Makefile. In that case, `abspath` won't do the trick.

Comment: @wangx1ng  In that case, you want to do `BRANCH_NAME := $(abspath $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))/../..)`.  Trust me, you don't want to use `$(shell)` in a makefile unless it is necessary because the functionality is not available.  One of the reasons is, your "shell" solution has a subtle error.  It only works because you are calling `>make` from the same directory as your `Makefile`.  If it were different, and you used `-f Makefile` option, it would go wrong very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but I've tested it with `BRANCH_NAME := $(abspath $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))/../..)` and it literally gives me `/home/e2/branchname`, not the `branchname` itself.

Comment: @wangx1ng oh I see, you just want one word.  OK then add `$(notdir)`:  `BRANCH_NAME := $(notdir $(abspath $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))/../..))`

Comment: Yeah, `notdir` makes it right. Really need to read some Makefile documentation when get some time, thank you though!

Answer (score 3):

I came up with this:

`ENVIRONMENT := $(shell basename $(dir $(abspath $(dir $$PWD))))`

If this were executed, you'd have:

`ENVIRONMENT=projectname`